# Parse: Progress for query

Tags: parse-platform

I have a bunch of questions (~1000 rows) stored in parse. The user can update the local database from the server by downloading all rows.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
[query setLimit:1000];
NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];
```

Is it possible to get a progress on this query download?
If a user is on a slow network, I want to show the progress if the download takes a long time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're below 1000 items, you can download them with a single PFQuery. Then Parse framework will not give you an indication of progress. If however it's more than 1k rows you'll have to iterate over all of them using several PFQueries with limit and skip properties, then you can make your own progress implementation.